# C++ How to set char array to hexadecimal enum

Tags: c++

Here is my enum:

```
enum ServerOpcode : uint16_t{
    SMSG_AUTH_CONNECTION_RESPONSE                    = 0x001,
    SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST_RESPONSE                      = 0x002,
    SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST_RESPONSE_TEST                 = 0x0A6,
};
```

Here is my char array:

```
enum { body_length = 1024 };
enum { header_length = 8 };
char header_[header_length];
char body_[body_length];
char data_[header_length + body_length];
void PreparePacket(ServerOpcode serverOpcode, std::string message);
```

Here is how I try to combine them:

```
void Packet::PreparePacket(ServerOpcode serverOpcode, std::string message) {
    header_[header_length] = serverOpcode;
    strcpy(body_, message.c_str());
    strcpy(data_, header_ );
    strcat(data_, body_);
    size_t size = sizeof(header_)/sizeof(*header_);
    std::cout << "Header: " << header_ << std::endl;
    printf("%x\n",serverOpcode);
    printf("%s\n",(*header_));
    std::cout << "Size: " << size << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Whole message: " << data_ << std::endl;
}
```

All I want to do is to get `serverOpcode` and perpend it in front of message. I want hexadecimal header and string message which I want to server over TCP with Boost ASIO.

However those seems to be not same:

```
    printf("%x\n",serverOpcode);
    printf("%s\n",(*header_));
```

Why is that? How can I fix it?

Comment: `size_t size = sizeof(header_)/sizeof(*header_);` -- wouldn't that be `header_length`?

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: Perhaps you could combine the various snippets into one [mcve] that allows us to copy & paste & compile & run & verify...

Comment: use keyvalue pair instead of enum?

Comment: @PuiHoLam what do you mean? Can you please make an answer example ?

Comment: I read that wrong sorry... anyway use this snprintf(header_,header_length,"%x\n",serverOpcode);

Comment: What is this used for? Can you please form up an answer ?

Comment: What is this `"%x\n"` ?

Comment: You wanted to turn the enum into hex string and put into the char array header_ right? Then just do the code 
var serverOpcode=SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST_RESPONSE_TEST;
snprintf(header_,header_length,"%x\n",serverOpcode); 
std::cout << header_;
gives "a6" as output

Comment: what's `enum { body_length = 1024 };`?? Why not `static constexpr auto body_length = 1024;`? Why are you using so much C style in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
header_[header_length] = serverOpcode;
```

assigns the byte value of the enum into the memory address header_+8.
You should replace this code with

```
snprintf(header_,header_length,"%x\n",serverOpcode);
```

which safely formats the byte value into hex string and stores into header_. By safely, I meant header_length restricts the function from writing into out of bound memory area.